# Display a particular user and all their information stored on parse on a different View Controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2, local-datastore

In my app each user sets up a profile page and all this info is stored on Parse. When the current user hits a button it segues to a tableViewController that displays in cells all the other users on the app. In each cell there is a button which the user presses to view the full profile page of the user that they have selected. I have a VC set up to hold all the info I just don't know how to display the particular user that the current user has selected into it. How do I single out the chosen users information? I have read the Parse documentation on relational queries but I can't seem to get my head around it. https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries-relational-queries

So in finer detail basically all my users are displaying on a VC. It has  name and profile picture, when the user clicks on the info button beside a certain user it should open a new screen and display all of this users information stored on Parse.

I have tried creating a static outside the class

```
struct Data { var OtherName:String! var id:String! }
```

And then in my ViewDidLoad:

```
    let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    //  otherQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    query.whereKey("username", notEqualTo:PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (users: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            // success

            print(users!.count)
            for user in users! {
                self.imageFiles.append(user["image"] as! PFFile)
                self.instrumentText.append(user["instrument"] as! String)
                self.nameText.append(user["name"] as! String)
                self.ageText.append(user["age"] as! String)
                // self.locationText.append(user["location"] as! PFGeoPoint)

                var singleData = Data()
                singleData.id = user.objectId
                singleData.OtherName = user["name"] as! String
                print("\(singleData)")


            } // users
```

Then on the VC that the info button segues to I am trying to call it and upload each label with just the user that was selected.

```
        self.userName.text = "" as String
```

But the "" is staying blank.

Then I was thinking maybe if I add that when the more info button is pressed that the user it was pressed on gets chosen and is added to a chosen string on Parse and then I just have to call the user from the chosen string when I am on the chosen users profile page and call the info that way and then when the user clicks the back button the user is no longer chosen. It just seems like I would be adding and taking away a lot of users to "chosen" in Parse is there a better way?

I am able to display all the users info but how do I just display a chosen user from Parse without using the objectId because at the top of each cell it will return a different user here each time depending on settings previously set on a different VC such as only show users in a certain age bracket etc. I know I must set an Id of some sort on button touched but I am at a complete loss. The only online help out there that I can find is set for other languages eg. https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#users-querying>
So I guess my question is :

1.Does anyone know a tutorial they could point me towards.

2.Does anyone know how I even get started and I can go from there myself.

3.Can anyone help?

*Swift and Parse newbie little to no experience in other languages.

New code in firstVC:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
if segue.identifier == "userProfileDetailsSegue" {
    if let indexPath = resultsPageTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

        let controller = (segue.destinationViewController) as! UserProfileDetailsViewController

  ***error here: UserProfileDetailsViewController.userToShowDetail = indexPath.row
    //line above is the one I can't get to work it needs to equal to the cell selected?
    }
  }
}
```

New Code in destinationVC:

```
 var userToShowDetail: PFUser? {
    didSet {
        self.configureView()
    }
}

func configureView() {
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    if let userToShowDetail: PFUser = self.userToShowDetail {
        if let label = self.userName {
            nameText.append(userToShowDetail["name"] as! String)

           // self.nameText.append(user["name"] as! String)


    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to do a couple of things for this to work. First, in the view controller that you're using to show another user's information, you need to set a property like `var userToShowDetail: PFUser?`. Then in your view with all of the users of your app, you need to create a segue to bring them from the current view to the detail view. Assuming you're using a TableView, you can connect just one prototype cell to the detail view you're trying to navigate. Then you'll need to override `prepareForSegue` and set the new view controller's user equal to the user at the row that was selected. I don't know how you're storing your objects of user's of your app, but you should probably be able to do something like this.

```
override fun prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if segue.identifer == "segueToShowDetailInfo" {
        //get the index path for the row that was selected
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        //get the PFUser object for that particular row
        let userToShow = self.appUsers[indexPath.row]
        //create your new view controller
        let newVc = segue.destinationViewController as! DestinationVC
        //assign the new vc's property to your object
        newVc.userToShowDetail = userToShow
    }
}
```

But in your query, you probably shouldn't have a separate array of the the different parts of the user's data. You should just make one array, call it `var appUsers = [PFUser]()` and then when you get a user back in your query, just say:

```
for user in users! {
    self.appUsers.append(user) as! PFUser
}
```

There, now you have a whole array of objects that holds a reference to every user. When someone is using your app, and selects a cell, then you can perform the prepare for segue method as above.

Note that I also noticed you have a `didSet` on your variable in your new view controller. Calling a function to update the UI after this variable is set will not work, and may crash, because the view controller doesn't have a window yet.

Comment: Hi @pbush25 thank for your help its definitely the right track. I nearly have it worked out except for the last line in the code on VC1. I edited my answer above to show the new code. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: How are your storing your objects that you're using to populate the tableView?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. How are you storing the data? Are you using your own array? Or are you using a PFQueryTableViewController?

Comment: I'm not using PFQueryTableViweController, I was but then ran into trouble. I have all my users data stored on Parse as string columns under the className _Users. I am calling them then like this:                                    var imageFiles = [PFFile]()                                                                           var instrumentText = [String]()
var nameText = [String]()
Shite have I done something really stupid???

Comment: I want to know, after you've queried for all the user's and their data, how are you storing this information. IN your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function, you have to have something like `let object = myArrayOfObjects[indexPath.row] as? PFObject`, do you not?

Comment: This is my query I have it in the view did load.                                             `let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
query.whereKey("username", notEqualTo:PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (users: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
if error == nil {
print(users!.count)
for user in users! {
self.imageFiles.append(user["image"] as! PFFile)
self.instrumentText.append(user["instrument"] as! String)
self.nameText.append(user["name"] as! String)
 }  self.resultsPageTableView.reloadData()
 } else { print("error") }   } `

Comment: Ah okay, I'll update my answer to show yo what you should be doing then.

Comment: Sorry about this you probably think I am thick! I have been trying my hand at swift for the past while and I think I jumped in a bit too deep but it's too late to turn back now as I've too much done.

Comment: One last question where do these lines go: 
 
        `self.imageFiles.append(appUsers["image"] as! PFFile)
        self.instrumentText.append(appUsers["instrument"] as! String)
        self.nameText.append(appUsers["name"] as! String)`                                                                      now that I have replaced them with :
               ` for user in users! {
                    self.appUsers.append(user as! PFUser)
                }`

Comment: You don't need them, or the arrays you were appending to anymore. In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` now in order to set the properties of the cell, you can do something like `let userObject = appUsers[indexPath.row] as! PFObject!` and then get access to that information like `cell.instrumentText.text = object["instrument"]` and so on.

Comment: I am so sorry to be bugging you again... its returning error array index out of range. I know why, its the call to display image.Tried adding PFFile to the appUsers array but it didn't work. Will I just ask another question and leave you alone? `let userObject = appUsers[indexPath.row] as PFObject
singleCell.usersName.text = userObject["name"] as? String
imageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
if imageData != nil {
let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)        singleCell.usersProfileImage.image = image`

Comment: You're getting an array out of bounds exception because you never populate `imageFiles`. What you should be doing is something like `singleCell.usersProfileImage.file = object["image"] as! PFFile` and then `singleCell.usersProfileImage.loadInBackground` if you're using a `PFImageVIew` which I would recommend.

Comment: I have been trying since i was last talking to you to get the users info to display on the destinationVC and I can't seem to figure it out at all is there any chance you can help? I posted it as a new question here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33572660/set-a-property-that-updates-information-on-display-on-a-vc-swift/33573021?noredirect=1#comment54926968_33573021)