# Set a property that updates information on display on a VC swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, properties, swift2

I have 2 view controllers, VC1 displays all the users on my apps basic info, when you press a more info button in a certain cell it segues to a new VC that displays the users full profile that was in the cell that you previously pressed.

With help I have everything working except for how to display the results on VC2. I am trying to set a property in the VC2.  I also tried for

This code is returning no errors but displays nothing on the VC2.

I've tried set, get willSet, everything and can't crack it:

```
var userToShowDetail: PFUser? {
    willSet {
        self.configureView()
    }
}

func configureView() {
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    if let userToShowDetail: PFUser = self.userToShowDetail {
        if let label = self.userName {
            userName.text = userToShowDetail["name"] as! String?

        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
```

I tried this one but it returns nothing but an empty VC:

```
var userToShowDetail: PFUser?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let appUsers = userToShowDetail as PFUser? {

    self.userName.text = appUsers["name"] as? String

    self.userInstrument.text = appUsers["instrument"] as? String

    self.userAge.text = appUsers["age"] as? String

    self.userProfile.file = appUsers["image"] as? PFFile

    self.userProfile.layer.cornerRadius = self.userProfile.frame.size.width/2

    self.userProfile.clipsToBounds = true

    self.userProfile.loadInBackground()
    }
```

I have researched didSet and willSet but I am still at a loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated. What is the next step can someone point me to a tutorial or advise me please.

[willSet and DidSet purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006234/what-is-the-purpose-of-willset-and-didset-in-swift)
[Apple properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)

View Controller 1 segue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
if segue.identifier == "userProfileDetailsSegue" {
//get the index path for the row that was selected
let indexPath = self.resultsPageTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
//get the PFUser object for that particular row
let userToShow = self.appUsers[indexPath.row]
//create your new view controller
let newVc = segue.destinationViewController as! UserProfileDetailsViewController
//assign the new vc's property to your object
newVc.userToShowDetail = userToShow
}
}
```

Comment: Try an [exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) it might help you figure out where the problem is

Comment: can you show the code where you set `userToShowDetail` when pushing from vc1 to vc2 please?

Comment: @AndreSlotta sorry I updated my code there.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common mistake when you are newer to swift.
 - When you segue to VC2, and pass a value to "userToShowDetail".The "didSet" method of "userToShowDetail" will be called.
 - Unfortunately, at this point, your VC2's views are still nil.So you will get this error.
 - The solution is simple,add a "?" after each view in your "didSet" func.
And don't forget to call "didSet" func in VC2's viewDidload.

```
func configureView() {
if let userToShowDetail: PFUser = self.userToShowDetail {
    if let label == self.userName? {//add "?" to VC2's subviews 
        userName?.text = userToShowDetail["name"] as! String?//add "?" to VC2's subviews 
    }
  }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  configureView()//call mothed in didSet()
  // other thing you need to do
}
```

Comment: I don't think I get you. Is my code correct above in my didSet method? Where do I add the "?" in my didSet code above? Sorry complete novice at didSet etc.

Comment: @Grace I added some snippet.

Comment: Now it is getting an error on "if let label = self.userName?"            The error is on the ? inserted.  The error is: '?' must be followed by a call, member lookup, or subscript

Comment: change this line of code to "if let label == self.userName?"

Comment: New error "variable binding in a condition requires an initializer" on the { after "if let label == self.userName?"

Comment: In your case you should just get rid of this line of code.func configureView() {
if let userToShowDetail: PFUser = self.userToShowDetail {
        userName?.text = userToShowDetail["name"] as! String?//add "?" to VC2's subviews 
  }
}

Comment: Okay so now I have no errors, it doesn't crash or return any errors but it still is not updating the label called 'username' with the user info?

Comment: Did you add configureView() to viewDidload() ??